# "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/"

Tags: json, angular

```
extractData = (res: Response | any) => {
  return res.body || {};
}

getData() {
 return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/test',
      observe: 'response' 
      ).pipe(
      map(this.extractData));
}
```

The call is successful, I'm able to see the response in network tab but when I tried to log the response in console, I'm getting parse errors. Can anyone please help me

Comment: What is the data type of body received?

Comment: [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpclient-response-observe-events?ctl=1&embed=1&file=src/app/services/user.service.ts&hideExplorer=1) might help you

Comment: backend I'm running a spring boot app, created a rest controller returning a simple string, it is a get mapping and by default the response is json. In the front-end I'm able to see that string in the network tab but when i try to log I'm seeing parse errors "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/test"

Comment: So you are trying to parse string into json?

Comment: can you show the code you use to log the response?

Comment: this.testService.getData().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    });

Answer (score 0):

The `getData()` function doesn't have any return type mentioned.